# cant access Api response in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

[image: see this Image]

I cant access data object in the red circle (see image) but I can access it outside , please help as I cant understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you save the data you get from getTrendingVideo on another variable? If not, the class cannot access that piece of data. Using this.data means that the class has a property called data

Comment: please put your code with error message

Comment: Try to put all the data fetching inside a component lifecycle method `componentDidMount` and pass the data to the state then access the state value inside the `render` method. Please do check the react documentation for the state management inside class and MDN site for how this works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example of a class component with state

```
export default class extends React.Component {

 constructor() { this.state = {data:[]}; }

 componentDidMount() {
  //Fetch data
  getTrendingVideo.then() { res => this.setState({data: res})}
 }

 render() { 
  console.log(this.state.data)
 } 
}
```

Comment: Do you need any help?

Comment: yes , i guess its a syntax err